# find by hash value from an unordered_set which element is cumtomed type

Tags: c++

For example I have a class like this:

```
struct Foo {
  std::string unique_name;
  unsigned id;

  struct HashFunc {
    size_t operator()(const Foo &foo) const {
      return std::hash<std::string>()(foo.unique_name);
    }
  };

  struct KeyEqual {
    bool operator()(const Foo &lhs, const Foo &rhs) const {
      return lhs.unique_name == rhs.unique_name;
    }
  };
};
```

as you can see I want the field `unique_name` to the key for hashing.

then I put some `Foo`s in an `unordered_set`:

```
std::unordered_set<Foo, Foo::HashFunc, Foo::KeyEqual> my_set {{"Foo", 1}, {"Bar", 2}};
```

Now I'd like to find the element which `unique_name` is `Bar`, but I don't know how to write, the `std::set::find` function takes type `Foo` as argument, not `std::string`.

So how can I write something like `my_set.find("Bar")`?

Comment: I think you should rethink your design. An unordered_map with std::string as Key and unsigned as Value seems more intuitive given your sample.

Especially that your equal functor does not compare for equality seems messed up.

Comment: @lars that's a simple example, in real case there's a lot of fields and for some complicated reasons, the design of turning into a hash map is not considered, that's why I asked this question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to do something like `my_set.find("Bar")` you need to do two things:

1. Your C++ compiler must support the C++20 standard and you must enable C++20 when compiling your code.
2. Implement your comparison and hash classes to be "transparent". This boils down to implementing overloads that hash a `std::string` (or a `const char *`) in addition to your class, and implementing a comparison operator between your class and a string.

For more information [see the reference for `std::unordered_set::find`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/find).

Before C++20, your only option is to construct a temporary instance of your class and pass it to `find` instead of a string (this can be done by implementing an appropriate constructor and relying on implicit conversions).